# Error:"Parameter count mismatch" in QSQLite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I wrote a `SQLite` database. `DB` is created but I can't insert message in it. I have a server and I want every message comes from client save in a DB.but during debug i get this error:

> "Listening to port " "INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message)
>   values(?,?,?)" QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

How should i connect my DB to my server?
Thanks a lot

**myserver.cpp:**

```
myserver::myserver(QObject *parent) :

QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void myserver::startserver()
 {
 int port = 6666;

connect(this,SIGNAL(newConnection()), this,SLOT(connectionAccepted()));

if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))

{
   qDebug() << "Could not start server ";
}

 else

{
   qDebug() << "Listening to port " ;
}

}


void myserver::connectionAccepted()
{
    qDebug()<<"Connected";

    m_client = nextPendingConnection();

    connect(m_client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSocket()));

    connect(m_client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

    QString IPAddress= m_client->peerAddress().toString();

    qDebug()<<"IP Address:"<< IPAddress;
}



void myserver::readSocket()
 {
  // qDebug()<<m_client->bytesAvailable();

    QByteArray message = m_client->readAll();

    qDebug() <<" Data in: " << message;

   QDate date=QDate::currentDate() ;

   qDebug() << date;

    m_client->write(message);

  }


void myserver::disconnected()
  {
     qDebug() << " Disconnected";

     m_client->deleteLater();

     exit(0);
  }




void MainWindow::createdata()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("DROP TABLE messages");
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE messages("
               "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
               "IPAddress varchar(20),"
               "Qdate date(10),"
               "message varchar(30))");
}



void MainWindow::insertMessage(QString IPAddress, QDate date, QString message)
{
    QSqlQuery query(database);
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO messages(IPAddress, date, message) values(?,?,?)");

    query.addBindValue(IPAddress);
    query.addBindValue(date);
    query.addBindValue(message);
    query.exec();

    //qDebug() << query.lastError();

    if (query.exec()) {

        qDebug() << "ok!";
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug() << query.executedQuery();
      qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your message may contain unexpected `,` or `'`.

Comment: @Zen: what do you mean?

Comment: If the message looks like this `"balabala, bala"`, this query is likely to fail.

Comment: You have a column named qdate, but try to insert into `date`. Try fixing it and see if the issue still manifests.

Comment: @EFraim: i did it. but it not solved.

Comment: Have you tried any query without any parameters? It appears this error might be caused by your DB connection being faulty.

Comment: @EFraim: yes i tried ,it work correctly. i know the problem is in insert message. it can't get value... IPAddress and message are empty and date is invalid:(

Comment: @Zen Parameters do not have such formatting problems.

Comment: Your code looks correct (in fact, it's pretty much identical with the "positional placeholders (version 2)" approach from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values)). Does it work with named placeholders?

Comment: @CL.: NO... it doesn't work